# move_uploaded_file is giving warnings

Tags: php, file-upload

I am trying to upload images into my web page but it doesnt work. it works locally! Maybe it has to do something with directory permissions or the path that I am using like this: ../post_images/name.jpg. What do you think? what I should do?

Here are the warning that I get:

```
Warning: move_uploaded_file(../post_images/del_piero2.jpg) 
    [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: 
    Permission denied in /home/vhosts/www.domain.com/admin/classes/controllers.class.php on line 324


Warning: move_uploaded_file() 
    [function.move-uploaded-file]:
    Unable to move '/tmp/phpuOHgMs'
    to '../post_images/del_piero2.jpg' 
    in /home/vhosts/www.domain.com/admin/classes/controllers.class.php on line 324
```

This is how I use it: **move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "../post_images/".$name);**

Comment: Check directory permissions on the target of the move.

Comment: Is the dir `/post_images/` writable?

Comment: Have you applied write permissions (`CHMOD 777`) to the destination directory (`/post_images/`)?

Comment: 777 is very a security concern

Comment: I changed the permissions to 777 and it works now, but is it safe to use 777 permissions for that folder?

Comment: If you're running the script on shared hosting it means, in theory, that everybody on that server can read and write to that directory. 755 is better, but doesn't always work on external hosts due to the way many hosting providers set up their hosting.

Comment: [This question has some more information](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8115159/can-people-write-a-php-file-to-my-chmod-777-folder) on the dangers of CHMOD 777.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

U need to set a folder permissions or right click in (windows) on FOLDER(check  it)
In unix ->

```
// Read and write for owner, read for everybody else
chmod("/somedir/somefile", 0644);

// Everything for owner, read and execute for others
chmod("/somedir/somefile", 0755);

// Everything for owner, read and execute for owner's group
chmod("/somedir/somefile", 0750);
?>
```

Comment: Finally someone cares about setting correct permissions. Thank You for not using 777 or 666 :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the error is pointing to permissions.

There's a few ways you can change this, the easiest comes by opening your FTP client, right clicking on the directory and changing the permissions that way.

You can also use the chmod() function (ex. chmod(/path/to/directory, 0777)). The number you enter correlates to some level of read, write, execute level of security on the directory.

Give that a try and see what happens.