# Writing to file without right permissions with PHP

Tags: php, file-writing

I'm trying to create a installation script for my PHP(CodeIgniter) app and i need to write database info that i get from user to CI database conf file.  Of course i run into permissions problem doing so because config directory doesn't have write permission.  So my question is how would this be possible without making user who installs my app to manage folder permissions him/herself.

Comment: Have you tried chmod'ing the file before you write to it?

Comment: if it was possible, what was the use of the permissions system?

Comment: @Ben have you tried to read the question?

Comment: Yes I have - I meant using CHMOD in the code, not manually

Answer (score 1):

They have to have access to the webserver's folder read/write options on their end - many hosts don't let you do this through FTP access so you can't even do a direct solution using that - they may have to go through the Control Panel system to do this type of task.

There's no "Run this script and it'll change folder permissions" code out there - the end user will have to be savvy enough to know how to do this.

Comment: While I basically agree; wordpress solves this kind of thing by having you provide ftp credentials - and if it can't update/create the relevant files directly (more specifically, if the files aren't owned by the webserver user) it does so via ftp. That's pretty close to "Run this script and it'll change folder permissions"

Comment: This may be of help, but it looks like the solution isn't 100% good either. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8115159/can-people-write-a-php-file-to-my-chmod-777-folder - By the way, WordPress is typically installed by "activating it" on a webhost and during that time they create the proper folders and whatnot that are needed.

Comment: What is the pattern of that process in WordPress, i mean if he doesn't have permissions to write to directory? I would imagine it would be something like generate a the file put it into temp folder and replace initial config file with the temp one. Is it so?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
- setup script checks permission on configuration files at startup
- if the files are not writeable, ask user to manually set permission manually (using FTP)
- after setup finishes the execution, use `chmod` command to make the files not writeable
- after the setup is completed, ask the user to delete the setup scripts for security reasons (so the setup is not run again by someone else)
```

You can use `chmod` to change the folder/file permission:

```
// Everything for owner, read and execute for others
chmod("/somedir/somefile", 0755);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php

Comment: This would be last option for me, because i would really want to avoid making user to go to ftp and make changes to folder permissions.

Comment: Ok, but how will the user will deploy the initial files? Give some more information about what you would like the user to do when he is deploying your app

Comment: they do deploy the app via FTP but this could by done by my grandmother, teaching them to manage folder permissions is rather harder and increases the the security risks imho. On the other hand to chmod some dir that isn't created by php u still need to give permissions manually.