# PHP cannot assign rights on directory

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu

I want to create a `directory` in the script of my page :

```
$critere = array();
$critere["bien_code"] = read_post_int("pk");
$name = "parcelle_". $photo->lireBienPhotoSeq().".png";
if ( ! file_exists (RP_PHOTO_PARCELLE) )
    mkdir(RP_PHOTO_PARCELLE, 0777, true);
$dest = RP_PHOTO_PARCELLE . $name;
```

The problem is that the `rights` of the `directory` is just **755** when I make a `ls -l` at the server ! So why isn't the direcory's right 777 ?

Comment: Why would you need the directory to be `777`? that's the most dangerous permission level you can have for an upload directory.

Comment: *"The mode is also modified by the current umask."* -- https://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php

Comment: did you try this one http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`chmod`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php) after creating the the directory.

So your code should look like this

```
$critere = array();
$critere["bien_code"] = read_post_int("pk");
$name = "parcelle_". $photo->lireBienPhotoSeq().".png";
if ( ! file_exists (RP_PHOTO_PARCELLE) )
    mkdir(RP_PHOTO_PARCELLE, 0777, true);
chmod(RP_PHOTO_PARCELLE, 0777); //<------ new line added for giving access
$dest = RP_PHOTO_PARCELLE . $name;
```

**NOTE:** Providing 0777 access to folder is bad idea. It involves high security risk.For risk involved see [here](https://superuser.com/questions/273530/what-are-the-risk-associated-while-setting-file-directory-permission-to-0777) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8115159/can-people-write-a-php-file-to-my-chmod-777-folder) If you understand the risk and still required to give 0777 access use it otherwise please try to avoid it

Comment: I want to make it 777 because in my project there is an Android app which will post photos to this directory ! So the directory's rights should be 777 !

Answer (score 1):

You should have to use chmod

```
// more code
chmod($path, 0755);

or 
chmod($path, 0777);
```

Answer (score 0):

The also have to take care of the processes umask for this:

```
umask(0);
mkdir(RP_PHOTO_PARCELLE, 0777, true);
```

But as mentioned in the comments: this is bad practice. Such a permission pattern should be avoided whenever possible.